# Skeleton of finitely generated modules

Tags: category-theory, modules

If $A$ is a pid, then let $C$ be the category of finitely generated  $A$-modules. Is there a skeleton of $C$ that can be described explicitly? I imagine that the structure theorem can be used to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't you say that the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID can be restated as "modules of the form $R^n\oplus \prod_{i=1}^m R/(p_i^{e_i})$, $p_i$ prime, $n,m,e_i$ nonnegative integers, form a skeleton of the category?